# How to concat multiple columns value by each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to develop a generic excel formula to concat strings among columns by each row and returned as an array format.

I know how to do it by applying the formula, such as =A1:A2&B1:B2&C1:C2

For example:

[image: Example]

However, I would like to have a shorter version, because there are multiple rows and columns in my source of data.

The generic formula I could think of is like

=concat(OFFSET(A1,,,2,3))

Any idea would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:C1)`, then dragging the formula down?

Comment: I need it to be returned of array format for feeding to another function.

Comment: TEXTJION function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the latest Excel version, you can use a combination of `BYROW`, `LAMBDA` and `TEXTJOIN` functions. As stated [here](https://exceljet.net/functions/byrow-function):

> The Excel BYROW function applies a LAMBDA function to each row of a given array and returns one result per row in a single array.

Use `BYROW` to apply `TEXTJOIN` as a lambda to each row of your range/array.

```
=BYROW(A1:C5,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,r)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I asked. Although I do not have excel function Byrow, I guess it should work. So I accepted it as an answer. Thank you for your reply.